# Multiple boxplots based on pandas groups

Tags: python, pandas

Here is how my dataframe looks like:

```
year    item_id      sales_quantity
 2014     1            10
 2014     1             4
 ...      ...          ...

 2015     1             7
 2015     1             10
 ...     ...          ...
 2014     2             1
 2014     2             8
 ...      ...          ...

 2015     2             17
 2015     2             30
 ...     ...          ...
 2014     3             9
 2014     3             18
 ...     ...          ...
```

For each item_id, I want to plot a boxplot showing the distribution for each year.

Here is what I tried:

```
data = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('electronics.csv')
grouped = data.groupby(['year'])
ncols=4
nrows = int(np.ceil(grouped.ngroups/ncols))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=nrows, ncols=ncols, figsize=(35,45), 
sharey=False)

for (key, ax) in zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axes.flatten()):
    grouped.get_group(key).boxplot(x='year', y='sales_quantity', 
    ax=ax, label=key)
```

I get the error `boxplot() got multiple values for argument 'x'`. Can someone please tell me how to do this right?

---

If I have only a single item, then the following works
`sns.boxplot(data.sales_quantity, groupby = data.year)`. How could I extend it for multiple items?

---

[Link to csv](http://www.sharecsv.com/s/c35fac1edbc0f3d703d41deecc8dac90/electronics_157_3cols.csv)

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this simple version for others...

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_table('sample.txt', delimiter='\s+')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True)
for n, i in enumerate(df['item_id'].unique()):
    idf = df[df['item_id'] == int('{}'.format(i))][['year', 'sales_quantity']].pivot(columns='year')
    print(idf)

    idf.plot.box(ax=axes[n])
    axes[n].set_title('Item ID {}'.format(i))
    axes[n].set_xticklabels([e[1] for e in idf.columns])

plt.show()
```

sample.txt

```
year    item_id      sales_quantity
 2014     1            10
 2014     1             4
 2015     1             7
 2015     1             10
 2014     2             1
 2014     2             8
 2015     2             17
 2015     2             30
 2014     3             9
 2014     3             18
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply! can you please edit your answer to incorporate a scenario where the item ids are random. For example, 123, 456, 216, etc

Comment: @user1274878 Updated, it will work with random id now.

Comment: Getting an error: `KeyError: "['year'] not in index"`

Comment: @user1274878 Hmm...That's weird, because I've never `year` column as index. I will attach my full code. Please check again.

Comment: thank you for your help! I have edited my post with a link to the csv. Can you please try at your end

Comment: Great, that worked! Any quick way to have the code show the plots in a grid rather than a single row?

Comment: @user1274878 Updated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check comment on the code.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('electronics_157_3cols.csv')
print(df)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(df['item_id_copy'].unique()), sharey=True)
for n, i in enumerate(df['item_id_copy'].unique()):
    idf = df[df['item_id_copy'] == int('{}'.format(i))][['year', 'sales_quantity']].pivot(columns='year')
    print(idf)

    idf.plot.box(ax=axes[n])
    axes[n].set_title('ID {}'.format(i))
    axes[n].set_xticklabels([e[1] for e in idf.columns], rotation=45)
    axes[n].set_ylim(0, 1)  # You should disable this line to specify outlier properly. (but I didn't to show you a normal graph)

plt.show()
```

[image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('electronics_157_3cols.csv')
print(df)

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 5, sharey=True)

gen_n  = (n for n in range(1, 11))
gen_i = (i for i in df['item_id_copy'].unique())

for r in range(2):
    for c in range(5):
        n = gen_n.__next__()
        i = gen_i.__next__()
        idf = df[df['item_id_copy'] == int('{}'.format(i))][['year', 'sales_quantity']].pivot(columns='year')
        print(idf)

        idf.plot.box(ax=axes[r][c])
        axes[r][c].set_title('ID {}'.format(i))
        axes[r][c].set_xticklabels([e[1] for e in idf.columns], rotation=0)
        axes[r][c].set_ylim(0, 1)

plt.show()
```

[image]